# DotNetZip add files without creating folders

Tags: c#, zip, directory, dotnetzip

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
    {
        zip.AddFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
    zip.Save("test.zip"));
}
```

Each time I add a file, it's creating a new subfolder for it.

So I want to end up with:

```
test.zip
    -  myDoc.doc
    -  myPdf.pdf
```

but I'm ending up with:

```
test.zip
    -  myDoc.doc
        -  myDoc.doc
    -  myPdf.pdf
        -  myPdf.pdf
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

How about just:

```
zip.AddFile(file,"");
```

or

```
zip.AddFile(file,@"\");
```

Comment: Thats makes it even worse. A filepath of for example `Documents\Process\Practices\text.doc` will create a subfolder in the .zip for each level in the path so you end up with `test.zip -> Documents -> Process -> Practices -> text.doc`.

Comment: @Fosco This works.  Is there any complete documentation for this?  I am using IonicZip.dll from nuGet.

Comment: dotnet zip compression ratio not good. i zip a 152 KB doc file with dotnet zip and when zip was created then i was zip file size was 136KB. is there any tweak exist which create small size zip file. share the knowledge. thanks

Comment: @Mou - doc files are now like .zip files, and they are already mostly compressed.  There are still sections inside that aren't compressed - so that external programs can read out property/summary information, etc. - but generally, they're already pretty compact.

Comment: @Fosco thank you for great solution. You save my time.

Answer (score 0):

Becouse aproved answer was 4 years ago now a days is another way (more elegant) to do this, if you want compres all file in directory (code above look like it) you can use:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourceDirectoryName, destinationArchiveFileName, compressionLevel, includeBaseDirectory)
```

You are interest with last parameter (includeBaseDirectory) and passing false value.

More info you can find here: [CreateFromDirectory(String, String, CompressionLevel, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_CreateFromDirectory_System_String_System_String_System_IO_Compression_CompressionLevel_System_Boolean_)

Answer (score -2):

```
zip.AddFile(file, "..\...\".ToString.Replace("..\...\", null))
```

Answer (score -3):

This is what I did and it worked.

```
zip.AddFile(file, "..\...\".ToString.Replace("..\...\", Nothing))
```

It sends the file back to 2 folders and replaces the .....\ with Nothing.