# Creating a zip file with ionic.zip

Tags: c#, zip, ionic-zip

I have the following code set up to create a zip file of a set of doucments:

```
    public bool CreateDocumentationZipFile(int documentIdentifier, string zipDestinationPath, IList<string> documentPaths)        
    {
        bool zipped = false;

        if (documentPaths.Count > 0)
        {
            using (ZipFile loanZip = new ZipFile())
            {
                loanZip.AddFiles(documentPaths, false, zipDestinationPath);
                loanZip.Save(string.Format("{0}{1}.zip",zipDestinationPath, documentIdentifier.ToString()));
                zipped = true;
            }
        }

        return zipped;
    }
```

The issue I have is that when the zip file is created, the folder structure is maintaned within the zip file:

e.g

I am creating a zip of a selection of documents located at

> C:\SoftwareDevelopment\Branches\ScannedDocuments\

When the created zip file is opened, there is a folder structure within the zip as follows:

Folder 1 ("SoftwareDevelopment")

Inside Folder 1 is folder 2 ("Branches")

Inside Folder 2 is folder 3 ("ScannedDocuments")

the scanned documents folder then contains the actual scan files.

Can anyone tell me how I can just have the scan files in the zip without the folders path being maintained?

Comment: Try adding a back slash (\) in the end of the path.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125607/dotnetzip-add-files-without-creating-folders

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [documentation](https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/ee0b15f2-2aaa-af65-7d25-586a7f8c0cc8.htm) states that the third parameter

> **directoryPathInArchive (String)**
>   *Specifies a directory path to use to override any path in the file
>   name. This path may, or may not, correspond to a real directory in the
>   current filesystem. If the files within the zip are later extracted,
>   this is the path used for the extracted file. Passing null (Nothing in
>   VB) will use the path on each of the fileNames, if any. Passing the
>   empty string ("") will insert the item at the root path within the
>   archive.*

So if you always want to have the files added to the root of your zip archive, change

```
loanZip.AddFiles(documentPaths, false, zipDestinationPath);
```

to

```
loanZip.AddFiles(documentPaths, false, "");
```