# Create zip file without inclusion of folders.

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

i have tried below code, and it is creating zip file . but the problem is when i unzip it , i have seen that it is saving my file (csv file) but with all root folder. i just want that when i unzip my zip file, there should be only csv file , not all root folder.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();
zipFile.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
zipFile.Password = "password";
var imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Report.csv");
zip.AddFile(imagePath, string.Empty);    
var saveToFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Report.zip");
zipFile.Save(saveToFilePath);
```

Can anyone please help me .?

Comment: What is the relevance of the password?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli i want to protect my zip file with password. that's why  i have given password.

Comment: I understand that, but what is the relevance? Your question is asking about how the file extracts. Is the behaviour different if you don't use a password?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli yes, i am getting same result whether i will use password or not.

Comment: I edited your title.  Password is irrelevant.

Comment: @B.K. i have tried that solution , but got an error Access is denied on zip.save line

Comment: @b.k. tried solution from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125607/dotnetzip-add-files-without-creating-folders and it worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store only files in zip without folder which contains these files then you must use:

```
zipFile.Options.StorePath = StorePathMode.NoPath;
```